# Instantiating a class, passed in java?

Tags: java, objective-c, instantiation

I have a query regarding instantiating a new object in java from a class passed as a parameter in a method, for example:

```
void myMethod(Class aReceived){
    object = new aReceived       // object will be a superclass of aReceived
}
```

I have seen this done using objective-C in a couple of lines but am uncertain how it works in java.

can you help?

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: I have used the aReceived.newInstance(); and initially I received an error like this: unreported exception java.lang.InstantiationException; must be caught or declared to be thrown. I resolved by adding the 'throws Exception' to the end of the myMethod declaration, which appears to have cleared up. However I am now having trouble calling the method: have tried using myMethod(testClass); where testClass is one which I have also defined in the code. Any ideas? Thanks again for your help ;)

Comment: Added another section to my answer below to address the problem you're describing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to create an object via the no-arg constructor:

```
void myMethod(Class<?> aReceived) {
  Object newObject = aReceived.newInstance();
  ...
}
```

If you want to create an object via a two-arg constructor (taking String, int):

```
void myMethod(Class<?> aReceived) {
  Object newObject = aReceived.getConstructor(String.class, int.class)
      .newInstance("aaa", 222);
  ...
}
```

Finally, you can use generics to properly set the type of the `newObject` variable (on top of either of the above snippets):

```
void myMethod(Class<T> aReceived) {
  T newObject = aReceived.getConstructor(String.class, int.class)
      .newInstance("aaa", 222);  
  ...
  // Sadly, due to erasure of generics you cannot do newObject.SomeMethodOfT() 
  // because T is effectively erased to Object. You can only invoke the 
  // methods of Object and/or use refelection to dynamically manipulate newObject
}
```

[Addendum]

How do you call this method?

Option 1 - when you know, in code-writing time, what class you want to pass to the method:

```
myMethod(TestClass.class)
```

Option 2 - when the name of the class to be instantiated is known only in runtime, as a string:

```
String className = ....; // Name of class to be instantiated
myMethod(Class.forName(className));
```

Comment: I have used the aReceived.newInstance(); and initially I received an error like this: unreported exception java.lang.InstantiationException; must be caught or declared to be thrown.

Comment: Yep thats what I needed, I also had to add a few lines of 'try' and 'catch' to handle exceptions, even though they dont actually do anything, the java compiler seems to want to see them anyway. I initially thought I'd made typing errors but it seems that its java protocol of some kind to expect these.

Answer (score 3):

`Class` has a method on it called [`newInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29) for creating instances of that class. You might also look into the whole [`java.lang.reflect` package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html).

Answer (score 3):

```
object = aReceived.newInstance();
```

This assumes that the class has a no-arguments constructor.

Answer (score 1):

If you have only a default constructor you may do something like this:

```
aReceived.newInstance();
```

If you need to pass parameters you can not use this method. But you may manage this while determing which is the right constructor with `getConstructor(Class<?> parameterTypes ...)`

e.g. if you want to pass a string as only parameter you might do it like this:

```
Constructor ctor = aReceived.getConstructor(String.class);
object = ctor.newInstance("somestring");
```